# Sending complex parameters to WEB API

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am having trouble sending a JSON complex object to my User control in my web api project. I keep getting a 404. I have some controls working (anything with a route /api/{control}/{action}/{id}) but nothing with a route (/api/{control}/{action}/{user}) will work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

the Route configuration

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "UserApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{User}");
```

The user object

```
public class User
{
    public String UserLoginName { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

}
```

The controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public Models.User AddUser([FromBody]User targetUser)
    {
        var userDTO = new UserDTO();
        var businessUser = userDTO.GetNewBusinessObject(targetUser);
        return userDTO.GetNewServiceObject(businessUser.Add());
    }
```

The json request

```
POST http://localhost:54002/api/user/AddUser HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:54002
content-length: 69
content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8

"{"UserLoginName": "steve ","UserID":-2147483637,"IsDeleted":false}"
```

Comment: Did you alter the route config to have user as last param? You're passing the user in the body, so you don't need that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the **webapi route**, as it's expecting a user as the last param. You can just set this to {`Id`} as optional, just like the default.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Also, make sure the API controller is `UserController`.

When you post from Fiddler, the JSON should look like this...

```
{"UserLoginName": "steve", "UserID": -2147483637, "IsDeleted": false }
```

Instead of...

```
"{"UserLoginName": "steve ","UserID":-2147483637,"IsDeleted":false}"
```

Take a look at the [`routes here`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: THank you so much!.The route isnt case sensitive

Comment: @gh9, no problem...I realised after typing that, I will remove it now :)

Answer (score 1):

Your Json

```
      "{"UserLoginName": "steve ","UserID":-2147483637,"IsDeleted":false}"
```

Try this

```
  {"UserLoginName": "steve","UserID":"-2147483637","IsDeleted":"false"}
```

Code to post data for Web

```
    User ObjUs = new User();
    ObjUs.UserLoginName = "steve";
    ObjUs.UserID = -2147483637;
    ObjUs.IsDeleted = false;
     System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ObjSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
  object sSeralize = ObjSerializer.Serialize(ObjUs);
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:54002/api/user/AddUser HTTP/1.1");
   byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sSeralize.ToString()); // Input Data
   request.Method = "POST";
   request.Accept = "application/json";
   request.ContentType = "application/json";
   Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
   dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
   dataStream.Close();
   HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
   StreamReader result = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
   if(result !=null)
   {      
   if(!string.IsnullorEmpty(result.ReadToEnd()))
   {
    String sResponseData = result.ReadToEnd(); 
   }
   }


public class User
{
public String UserLoginName { get; set; }
public int UserID { get; set; }
public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
 }
```

Check this site to create structured Json String : http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: {"UserLoginName": "steve","UserID":"-2147483637","IsDeleted":"false"} still 404s on me